# Fsharp ASP mvc 4 project in monoDevelop 3.0.3.2 -> error AspNetMvc3' not found

Tags: f#, monodevelop

I just installed the fSharp language bindings. I am trying to create a Fsharp ASP mvc 4 project in MonoDevelop 3.0.3.2 but I get this:

System.InvalidOperationException: Project type 'AspNetMvc3' not found.

Any ideas what I need to do next?